# AWS S3 Presigned urls error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm building a node app and I have an existing AWS account with uploaded images.

This is my code, I followed the documentation and some other questions that were posted here previously:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const s3 = new AWS.S3();
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: 'string',
  secretAccessKey: 'string',
  region: 'string'
 });
const myBucket = 'string-bucket';
const myKey = 'file-name.png';
const signedUrlExpireSeconds = 60 * 5;

const params = { Bucket: 'string-bucket' };
s3.headBucket(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log('there is an error!!!!', err, err.stack);
  else     console.log('this is what i got', data);
});

const url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
  Bucket: myBucket,
  Key: myKey,
  Expires: signedUrlExpireSeconds
});

console.log(url);
```

First it logged the url: `https://s3.amazonaws.com/` , just this, without any strings attached, and for the bucket is says `CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config`.

I don't see what I am missing, they keys are correct (I copied and pasted them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are updating the AWS config **after** you initialized the S3 SDK. Just put the following snippet above `const s3 = new AWS.S3();`:

```
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: 'string',
  secretAccessKey: 'string',
  region: 'string'
});
```

In the end you should have something like this:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: 'string',
  secretAccessKey: 'string',
  region: 'string'
});
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
```